# efficient alternative to if (a>b) in javascript for checking a variable range

Tags: javascript, performance, coding-style

I hope the title is not too generic nor misleading.

```
var blah;
if(a > 10) blah = 'large';
if(a <= 10 && a > 5) blah = 'medium';
if(a <= 5 && a >= 0) blah = 'small';
```

isn't there a more elegant and concise way to implement a range-check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a lot of range intervals you could go for something like this:

```
var ranges = [[10, 'large'],
              [5, 'medium'],
              [0, 'small']];

function range(n) { 
    for (var i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) { 
        if (n > ranges[i][0]) {
            return ranges[i][1]; 
        }
    }
    return 'default value';
}
```

This is not as flexible, as you cannot specify for each case wether to use `<` or `<=` but if I had a lot of ranges i might write something like this. The other answers are great, just thought I would add this as an idea.

Comment: this is an interesting idea. Just ends up being more effort in my particualr case that i care to deal with, but definitely nice scalable concept.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, use `else` clauses:

```
var blah;
if(a > 10){
    blah = 'large';
}else if(a > 5){
    blah = 'medium';
}else if(a >= 0){
    blah = 'small';
}
```

Since you are doing a simple assignment in each statement it could also be elegant to use a ternary expression, although many would argue that this is less readable:

```
var blah =
  a > 10 ? 'large'  :
  a > 5  ? 'medium' :
  a >= 0 ? 'small'  :
  undefined; // May want to choose a better default value for a < 0
```

Comment: I'm curious.  Would it make a difference in performance if the most likely "true" result comes first?  For example, if most of the data falls in the range of 'medium', does it make sense to have that as the first condition in the if else/if block?

Comment: @GMastros That is correct. There is no logical difference, but there could be a small performance difference.

Comment: @GMastros You can't put the medium check first. It would catch both large and medium (e.g. values of 20 would be detected as medium)

Comment: @PeteScott I think GMastros means the medium check from the OP's code: `a <= 10 && a > 5`

Comment: Right.  First make it work, then make it fast.  It does no good if you get the wrong results very quickly.

Comment: @Paulpro, i should be accepting your ansewr but i just really like the answer from @Reason, who deserves some `manna` for the unusual idea.

Comment: @tim I'm glad I could help. Accept whichever answer you like :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ternary operators`

```
var blah;

blah = a > 10 ? 'large' : (a > 5 ? 'medium' : 'small' ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

If range is constant, you can use combine switch statement and modulo.
Eg.

```
var blah;
switch(a-(a % 5)) {
    case 10:
        blah = 'large';
        break;
    case 5:
        blah = 'medium';
        break;
    case 0:
        blah = 'small';
        break;
    default:
        blah = 'large';
}
```

Of course, it can be used only when differences between each range are equal.